# Что делает sql-запрос?

Tags: sql

Помогите пожалуйста понять, что делает этот код:

```
Update [Cost].[ClassificatorRow] 
Set [Status1C] = 5, 
    [CommentEnsi] = CASE [TcsNote] 
                    WHEN '00-00000356' THEN [CommentEnsi] 
                    ELSE 'Была произведена замена с  Компьютер встраиваемый' + char(13) + char(10) + ISNULL([CommentEnsi],'') END, 
    [TcsNote] = '00-00000356', 
    [Name] = 'Новая утка', 
    [OrderNumber] = 'УТК-22', 
    [ManufactureManual] = '' 
Where [Code1C] = 14 and [Status1C] <> 5
```

Он должен получить в таблице позицию, где Code1C=14 и поставить в поле Name значение "Новая утка". Но вместо этого он присваивает это значение нескольким позициям. В чем ошибка и как правильно написать запрос?

Comment: если несокльким, значит все они попадают под условие `Where Code1C = 14 and Status1C <> 5`

Comment: собственно, для отладки обычно сначала делают выборку того, что хотят обновить `select * from Cost.ClassificatorRow Where Code1C = 14 and Status1C <> 5`

Comment: *Но вместо этого он присваивает это значение нескольким позициям.* Позиции - это поля или записи?

Comment: Позиции - это записи (строки)

Comment: Это какой-то безжизненный кусок кода выдергнутый или подглянутый в каком-то вероятно студенческом задании.

Comment: Обновляет записи по этому условию: ```[Code1C] = 14 and [Status1C] <> 5```
Возможно несколько строк походит под них?